# Mixing physical wall switches with IoT HA controls

Tags: smart-lights

I have just started my journey into IoT / Smart Home and I currently run a Home Assistant (HA) green with Zigbee/Matter extension.

One of my devices is a classical ceiling light array (5 bulbs), for which I installed an IKEA Tradfri, which again are connected to HA via Zigbee. So far, everything works.

I am having problems with the physical wall-mounted switch. If it is switched off, nothing works (of course), so I was thinking of replacing that switch with a Shelly switch of some sort to install behind the "normal" switch to be able to control the lights in this way (e.g. a [Shelly Plus 1PM WiFi & Bluetooth Relay Switch](https://www.amazon.de/dp/B0965J4HT5)) but I'm not sure if buying a ZigBee/Matter wall mounted switch like [Aqara Wireless Remote Switch](https://www.amazon.de/Aqara-Fernschalter-Konfigurierbare-Fernbedienung-Installation/dp/B094QL17GY) would be the better option.

EDIT: What I want to achieve is that using the wall-mounted switch is only operating the bulbs via Home Assistant/ZigBee, not physically switching on/off.

BUT: At the same time, I feel like there should still be a physical switch to PHYSICALLY switch off the bulbs in order to be able cut power.

Anyhow, as the MAIN way to operate the bulbs should be the HA-way via the wall-mounted switch, as this is how basically everyone will want to switch on/off the lights.

Any advise on this topic?

Comment: You need a smart switch that understands that it's talking to smart bulbs. Since you're using ZigBee, I'd suggest Innovelli or Zooz - they both make ZigBee switches that are designed to interact with ZigBee bulbs. I have a couple of the Innovelli switches and like them. They'll even operate the bulbs if your HA instance is down, thus meeting code in the US to allow first responders to turn lights on.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. Anyhow, both Inovelli and Zooz seem to only be available on the US American market (and also only caters to american formats). I'd need a European-style switch format.

Comment: You didn't mention where in the world you were located, so it was hard to know...

Answer (score 1):

**Note! Bypassing or shorten a wall switch should only be performed by an authorized electrician.**

Either you short the wall switch or bypass it. As the Tradfri needs to be powered all the time isn't replacing the wall switch with a automated wall switch a solution.

So either you have smart bulbs and shorten/bypass the wall switch or
Use standard bulbs and replace the wall switch with a automated one.

The other solution that I have is to place a box over the wall switch as I cant make any changes to the installation (rents).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Managing normal bulbs with an intelligent switch is not a good option as the bulbs should be controlled individually as they are illuminating different areas of the room.